# Image at Mac Mail App Signature not working

Tags: html, macos, email

In Mail App, I want to edit the signature with Image, the problem is when I change the .webarchive file content with this part:

```
<img width=138 height=150 src="http://www.example.com/signature.png">
```

It works fine, but if I try for local image like this:

```
<img width=138 height=150 src="\Users\XXX\Documents\signature.png">
```

It doesn't work.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a valid URL, not a file from your local computer.  The people you send mail to are not going to have that file on their computer.  If you want an image in your mail signature you're going to have to either attach it to every email (please don't) or have it hosted somewhere (which most email clients will block by default anyway).

Alternatively just don't have an image in your email signature.  They're obnoxious.

Comment: I want to attach it in every email, because as you said email clients block it if it is hosted somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`\Users\XXX\Documents\signature.png` is not a valid *URL*. If anything you have to use `file:///Users/...`. But you do know that only you will be able to see this signature and nobody you send the email to will, unless they happen to have the same file in the same directory, right?

Comment: But I tried to run the webarchive on Safari, it worked and showed the image with that URL. Anyway, I want this image to be dealt as attachment in every email, I don't know how to do that, in windows outlook it happens easily.